# Unable to use Java in Octave

Tags: java, octave

I'm using Octave 4.2.1 on Windows 10. When I type in the Octave console:

```
>> __have_feature__ JAVA
ans = 1
```

So java is enabled. Using the Command Prompt on Windows I found that I have java version "1.1.0_71". So java is present and running.
But when I try to call a java fuction in Octave I get:

```
cp = javaclasspath
error: unable to find Java Runtime Environment: software\javasoft\java runtime environment::Currentversion
```

And when I just type 'java -version':

```
>> java -version
error: 'java' undefined near line 1 column 1
```

I checked the environment variable for java:

```
>> getenv JAVA_HOME
ans = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71
```

Again, this looks fine. FInally I even tried to install Octave from scratch, but this did not solve the issue. My guess is that it has something to do with the 'software\javasoft\java runtime environment::CurrentVersion' but I'm unable to figure out what it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is likely connected to the difference of the bitness of Octave and your JRE. [This post raises](http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/Octave-4-installer-doesn-t-detect-JRE-at-install-time-td4670684.html) the same issue. That one was resolved by bringin the Octave bitness into line with JRE bitness. Make sure your Octave installation is 64-bit.

It is also worth checking you have the following variable specified:
[image]

Comment: @CeesMeijer This seems to be a problem with a windows Registry Key. Check if the key [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment] is holding the proper paths

Comment: @CeesMeijer since I have no issues I think you may rely on my settings as the reference ones. I have a folder named after the java version and the following variables under it: JavaHome="C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144", RuntimeLib="C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144\bin\client\jvm.dll". Make also sure that you use the same "bitness" of Octave and Java. e.g. you're not having 32-bit Octave and 64bit java.

Comment: I checked, and I have the same settings in my registry. Which also means that my JAVA_HOME environment variable was set to a different folder (with version 1.7). I corrected that, but unfortunately it does not solve the problem.

Comment: @CeesMeijer I've updated the answer with the reference to the forum post where the similar issue was raised. Try to align the bitness of Octave and JRE. Since your JRE is in "Program Files" it is likely that it is 64-bit. Make sure you're using Octave 64-bit.

Comment: @CeesMeijer btw you should also update your PATH variable.

Comment: @CeesMeijer please also check if my update with "currentversion" would help

Comment: You were right. And I found that I had two versions of Java on my system, of which the 1.8 version actually was 32 bit. I now installed the 64 bit version and it works. Thanks.

Comment: @AlexeyR. I don't have any "client" subdirectories, and have `jvm.dll` in `server` subdirectory.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you run the 64-bit version of Octave and you have the 64 bit version of JDK 11.0.5

In file `octave.vbs` write after line

```
Set wshShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
```

the line

```
wshShell.Environment("SYSTEM")("JAVA_HOME") = "c:\program files\java\jdk-11.0.5"
```

Then merge the following registry lines with your registry

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment]
"CurrentVersion"="11.0.5"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\11.0.5]
"JavaHome"="C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-11.0.5"
"RuntimeLib"="C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-11.0.5\\bin\\client\\jvm.dll"
```

*** EDIT: The code above, is for Windows 7. If you run Windows 10, change "client" with "server":

```
    "RuntimeLib"="C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-11.0.5\\bin\\server\\jvm.dll"
```

Comment: I followed your solution but I'm still getting the same "error: 'java' undefined near line 1 column 1". Any ideas?

Comment: @Starhowl, If you run Windows 10, change "client" with "server" (solution edited)

Comment: This works with latest JDK 13.0.2, thank you very much!